# ZF strange layout behavior

Tags: zend-framework

I have a strange behavior with ZF that I can't resolve. I have a layout.phtml and a login.phtml. So when the user is logged in the layout.phtml should be displayed else the login.phtml. This also works, but before displaying the login.phtml, ZF go through layout.phtml and I can confirm this due to errors in the error.log file.

Here what I have in the bootstrap:

```
public static function _initAcl()
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $acl = new BM_Acl($auth);

    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(
        new BM_Controller_Plugin_Acl($auth, $acl)
    );
}
```

Here what I have in the auth controller:

```
    public function indexAction() {


    $form = new BM_Form_Login();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            if ($this->_process($form->getValues())) {
                // We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page
                //json validation on login page
                $var = json_encode(array('valid' => true, 'redirect' => 'index'));
                echo $var;
                exit();
            } else {
                $var = json_encode(array('valid' => FALSE, 'error' => 'Authentication failed!', 'redirect' => 'auth'));
                echo $var;
                exit();
            }
        }
    }// end if is POST
    $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('login'); // special login page
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...
Regards
Andrea

P.S. This only happens when I start the application from a new browser window. If I refersh the login page, the layout is not called anymore...

Comment: I think better soulution is disable layout and put login layout content into index action template.

Comment: The code seems OK as far as I can tell, I've done the same many times. Are you absolutely sure that the other layout is also processed? Do you have any additional logic that could mess with your layouts?

Answer (score 1):

Views are for single pages.  If you have a singular page you wish to display with a template like layout.phtml, you would edit the index.phtml inside the index action's views directory.  If you want to disable the main layout

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
```

Or use a blank layout

```
$this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('blank');
```

Any code specific to a singular page should be done with a view.

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure, but the i think the layout is redered before the view scripts. You could try to put you logic inside the preDispatch Hook in your Controller.

```
public function preDispatch() {


    $form = new BM_Form_Login();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            if ($this->_process($form->getValues())) {
                // We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page
                //json validation on login page
                $var = json_encode(array('valid' => true, 'redirect' => 'index'));
                echo $var;
                exit();
            } else {
                $var = json_encode(array('valid' => FALSE, 'error' => 'Authentication failed!', 'redirect' => 'auth'));
                echo $var;
                exit();
            }
        }
    }// end if is POST
    $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('login'); // special login page
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Or use an ControllerPlugin:

[Zend Controller Plugin - Doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

When I understand right, you have a layout that you use on all pages, except for login. Instead of using the view for login as a layout, you should disable layout for this action and just render the login.phtml normally. You can do this by calling the following in your controller's loginAction, instead of `setLayout('login')`:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
```

This will just disable the layout, but the view is rendered normally.

If you want to do it your way, you have to place the login.phtml into the layout-path, not in the view-path (if you want a more detailed explanation, just ask in a comment).

Comment: Thank you the quick answer. I modified it this way, but the layout.phtml is still called somewhere...

Comment: How do you set the default layout, via `resources.layout` in application.ini? When your layout is still shown, my guess is, that somehow the layout is set to its default later on in the dispatch-process, e.g. via a Controller_Plugin.

Comment: I set the layout in the application like this : resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/". But the layout is not shown....